# Delete lines that contain X in specific column .csv

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv-simple

I currently use the following to delete all emails that contain `EXAMPLE`

```
sed -i '/EXAMPLE/d' newname.csv
```

However that deletes lines that have `EXAMPLE` in any of the columns. I want it to only delete lines that contain `EXAMPLE` in the second column. Columns are separated with tabs. (example below)

```
pa**s-***c.com  support@n**.com George Ka*****os    Athens  Athens  1****   GREECE
```

Due to tab problems none of the below that I have tried work, so alternatively I will cover to .txt and columns look like this

```
"pak**o.asia","jav***vip@live.com","T**iq Ja**id","Rajan Pur","punjab","33***0","PAKISTAN"
```

Comment: Do you want to keep lines where the 2md field is `fooEXAMPLEbar` or does `EXAMPLE` need to be the entire field?

Comment: Wait - it says delete the line? So... which should we do, do you think?

Comment: Sorry I was confused, if the second column has EXAMPLE anywhere in it, for example fooEXAMPLEbar that line should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -v '^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*EXAMPLE' <newname.csv >outfile
```

But you might need to use literal *<tab>* characters there depending on which `grep` you use.

The same goes for `sed` below. Be warned that using `-i` comes with certain filesystem security implications:

```
sed -i '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*EXAMPLE/d' ./file
```

Or maybe a little more tricky:

```
sed -i 'h;s/\t/\n/2;/\t.*EXAMPLE.*\n/d;g' ./file
```

For your example data w/ the commas:

```
sed -i '/^[^,]*,[^,]*EXAMPLE/d' ./file
```

Gets the whole line deleted when *`EXAMPLE`* is found before another comma after the first occuring comma.

Comment: How can I run this to delete without printing on screen? I will be running multiple commands one this file, EXAMPLE wont be the only word to remove.

Comment: The following doesn't work (to delete any emails with the word example in them) sed -i '/^[^\t]*\t[^\t]*example/d' ./newname.csv

Comment: I can't get it working. I have updated my first post with what it looks like after I convert to .txt - How would I do it with that format?

Comment: That didn't work and no email has commas - How could I do it with the "," separator (after I convert to .txt, see first post)

Comment: @Teddy291 - I just did another - you wanna try it? It's at the bottom. Weird about the tabs.

Comment: I don't think that did anything, the file size didn't change. Also where is the EXAMPLE word to delete?

Comment: It does nothing, just prints the data on screen

Answer (score 1):

Perl can do this quite handily:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print unless ( split )[1] =~ m/EXAMPLE/;
}
```

That's an unanchored regex - you might want `m/^EXAMPLE$/` instead.

This can one-liner-ify as:

```
perl -ne 'print unless ( split )[1] =~ m/^EXAMPLE$/';
```

Answer (score -1):

Such task is actually simpler and easier to understand using `awk`, only that awk has no in-place file edit:

`$ awk '$2 !~ /EXAMPLE/ {print $ALL}' old.csv > new.csv`

Comment: What is `{print $ALL}` supposed to do?

Comment: $ALL means the whole line. But note that the variable works for Linux but might not for some other OS. In that case one would use {print;} instead.

Comment: `$0` is the entire record in Awk. And it is printed by default. Your answer is incorrect on two counts.

Comment: @jasonwryan Would you care about mentioning **how** it is incorrect? Other than `$ALL` shall not be used in nawk, I have tested on Linux and Freebsd with 3 different implementations: mawk, gawk, nawk, and still fail to see how and where it was incorrect.

Comment: More correct `'$2 !~ /EXAMPLE/ {print $0}'`; idiomatic: `'$2 !~ /EXAMPLE/'`...

Comment: You didn't read my question at all. I *am* curious about what "Your answer is incorrect on two counts" means.